# Category where every object is a retract of every other object

Tags: category-theory

Are there non-trivial* categories where every object is a retract of every other object?

Does having this feature impose strong constraints on the structure of the category?

*meaning there are two objects that are not isomorphic

Comment: By "non-trivial", do you mean "at least two non-isomorphic objects"?

Comment: @AlvinL are you sure? I think that if you take the free category on two objects $A$ and $B$ generated by a retraction $f\colon A\to B$ (and its left inverse $g$) and a retraction $g'\colon B\to A$ (and its left inverse $f'$), $A$ and $B$ are not isomorphic.

Comment: @AlexKruckman oop, good catch!

Comment: @AlexKruckman Yes, that is what I meant

Comment: If the category has a terminal object it must be trivial. I'm wondering if such a category can have all finite coproducts in a non-trivial way

Comment: @JonasLinssen I don't follow your argument. Why cannot there be such a functor? Or what do u mean with "meaningful functor"?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Doesn't this example already answer the question here?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg It was a silly mistake. The idea was that for a forgetful functor, which reflects isomorphism classes (a rather strong condition tired me confused with being conservative), if the target category satisfies a Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein property this forces our example to be trivial. But these assumptions already fail for abelian groups as your example shows.

Comment: Ok. Just saying that deleting comments is not a good practice. Now, both the comment by Alex Kruckman to AlvinL and my comment to you don't make sense anymore to future readers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[There is](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10128/when-is-a-isomorphic-to-a3) an abelian group $A$ such that $A$ is isomorphic to $A^3$, but not isomorphic to $A^2$. So the full subcategory $\{A,A^2\}$ is an example.

---

Another example has already been mentioned by Alex Kruckman in the comments: Consider the category with two objects $A,B$ and generated by morphisms $i,s : A \to B$, $j,r : B \to A$ with $r \circ i = \mathrm{id}_A$ and $s \circ j = \mathrm{id}_B$. So $A$ is a retract of $B$, and vice versa. To really prove that $A$ and $B$ are not isomorphic in this category (without refering to a more concrete example), we need to figure out all the morphisms. For example, $j \circ s$, $r \circ s$, $j \circ i$ are distinct morphisms $A \to A$, and they generate $\hom(A,A)$ as a monoid, but not freely since for example

- $(j \circ s) \circ (j \circ s) = j \circ s$
- $(j \circ s) \circ (j \circ i) = j \circ i$
- $(r \circ s) \circ (j \circ s) = r \circ s$
- $(r \circ s) \circ (j \circ i) = 1$

So this seems to be the monoid $\langle x,y,z \mid x^2=x, \, xz=z,\, yx=y,\, yz=1 \rangle$.

You would have to work out a normal form for all the elements in $\hom(A,A)$, and then do the same for $\hom(B,B)$, $\hom(A,B)$, $\hom(B,A)$, and then verify that indeed there is no isomorphism $A \to B$.

So even though it is easy to describe this (universal) example of two objects which are rectracts of each other, it is not so easy to verify directly that the objects are not isomorphic. Maybe it is in fact easier to write down a more concrete example (as above for abelian groups).

Comment: A more elementary concrete example is the full subcategory of the category of topological spaces consisting of two objects: a closed disc, and the union of two closed discs intersecting in a point on the boundary of both discs. Probably there are even more elementary examples. And of course, once you have a concrete example, that proves that Alex’s universal example is an example.

Comment: Can you post this as a separate answer (brings extra visibility)?

Answer (score 4):

A more elementary concrete example than the abelian group example in Martin's answer is the full subcategory of the category of topological spaces consisting of two objects: a closed disc, and the union of two closed discs intersecting in a point on the boundary of both discs. Probably there are even more elementary examples.

And of course, once you have a concrete example, that proves that Alex’s universal example in comments *is* an example.